# Want to limit jQuery.lazyload() to a specific DIV's images

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

we know lazy load plugin enable us to download images on demand which is out of visible area of page and when user scroll down and image place holders are getting visible then lazy load plugin download images on demand.

the problem is lazy load plugin work for all the images but i want it to work for those images which are in specific div. suppose my div is in bottom of the page and that div has many image but div will not have any scroll bar. i want that when user scroll down to close to specific div and div comes to visible area of the page then images in that div view will be started downloading and visible.

how could i achieve it by lazy load plugin which will download images only for specific div without scroll bar.

let me know thanks.

Comment: Lazyload plugin works on those images which you yourself bind it to. Check jQuery documentation about selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your HTML is:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="blah.jpg" />
    <img src="blah2.jpg" />
    <img src="blah3.jpg" />
    ...
</div>
```

You simply do this:

```
$("#gallery img").lazyload();
```

Comment: thanks but i have one confusion that does it load image on demand with in only gallery div or does it effect other div may have images?

Comment: This will only affect the div that has an id of "gallery".